# Use cpanspec to create an RPM that installs a desktop file

Tags: perl, rpm-spec

I'm trying to convert some Perl code into an RPM. cpanspec does the job very nicely, accepting a .tar.gz file containing the Perl code, and generating a .SPEC file that actually generates a working RPM.

However, I can't work out how to modify the .SPEC file to make it install a desktop file. In principle, it should be as simple as adding these lines:

```
Source1:        myapp.desktop

...

desktop-file-install                               \                         
--dir=${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_datadir}/applications    \
%{SOURCE1}

xdg-desktop-icon install --novendor %{SOURCE1}
```

That doesn't work, any neither does any other variation. Usually, I get an error like this:

```
error: Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found:
   /usr/share/applications/myapp.desktop
```

I searched google exhaustively and, apparently, no-one in the history of computing has attempted this operation before. Either that, or I'm missing something really obvious.

**EDIT:** Following the suggestions below, this minimal .SPEC file produces the desired results. I used rpmbuild, and copied the desktop file and its corresponding image file in /rpm/SOURCES.

```
Name:           perl-MyApp
Version:        1.0
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        MyApp Perl module
License:        Distributable, see COPYING COPYING.LESSER
Group:          Development/Libraries
URL:            http://search.cpan.org/dist/MyApp/
Source0:        http://www.cpan.org/modules/by-module/MyApp-%{version}.tar.gz
Source1:        myapp.desktop
Source2:        myapp.png
BuildRoot:      %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-root-%(%{__id_u} -n)
BuildArch:      noarch
BuildRequires:  perl(ExtUtils::MakeMaker)
Requires:       perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_%(eval "`%{__perl} -V:version`"; echo $version))

%description
blah blah blah

%prep
%setup -q -n MyApp-%{version}

%build
%{__perl} Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=vendor
make %{?_smp_mflags}

%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

make pure_install PERL_INSTALL_ROOT=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT

find $RPM_BUILD_ROOT -type f -name .packlist -exec rm -f {} \;
find $RPM_BUILD_ROOT -depth -type d -exec rmdir {} 2>/dev/null \;

%{_fixperms} $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/*

mkdir %{buildroot}/usr/share/pixmaps/
cp -a %{SOURCE2} %{buildroot}/usr/share/pixmaps/myapp.png

desktop-file-install                                    \
--dir=${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_datadir}/applications         \
%{SOURCE1}

xdg-desktop-icon install --novendor %{SOURCE2}

%check
make test

%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%doc CHANGES COPYING COPYING.LESSER README
%{perl_vendorlib}/*
%{_mandir}/man3/*
/usr/share/applications/myapp.desktop
/usr/share/pixmaps/myapp.xpm
```

Answer (score 1):

You need that desktop file added to the `%files` section. I don't know how to automate it with `cpanspec`, but your specfile example doesn't have it listed, and that's exactly what `rpmbuild` told you was wrong.